# In-Place Ordering of Elements

Tags: d, in-place, phobos

Does Phobos have some variadic algorithm to order l-value reference arguments in place? Something like

```
int a=3;
int b=2;
int c=1;

orderInPlace(a,b,c);

// a is now 1
// b is now 2
// c is now 3
```

Also a functional variant, say `order(a, b, c)`, that returns a tuple would also be nice.

If not, I guess we should make use of `std.algorithm:swap`.

See also http://forum.dlang.org/thread/eweortsmcmibppmvtriw@forum.dlang.org#post-eweortsmcmibppmvtriw:40forum.dlang.org.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adam's solution works, although it uses a temporary copy of the elements. With a [small modification to std.algorithm](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/1858), it's possible to write a version which sorts the elements in-place:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;
import std.typecons;

struct SortableRef(T)
{
    private T * _p;
    @property ref T value() { return *_p; }
    alias value this;
    void opAssign(T * value) { _p = value; }
    @disable void opAssign(SortableRef!T value);
    void proxySwap(SortableRef!T other) { swap(*_p, *other._p); }
}

template PointerTo(T) { alias T* PointerTo; }
void orderInPlace(T...)(ref T values)
    if (!is(CommonType!(staticMap!(PointerTo, T)) == void))
{
    alias CommonType!T E;
    SortableRef!E[values.length] references;
    foreach (i, ref v; values)
        references[i] = &v;
    references[].sort();
}

void main()
{
    int a=3;
    int b=1;
    int c=2;
    orderInPlace(a, b, c);
    writeln([a, b, c]);
}
```

However, it is only practical if the values passed to `orderInPlace` are large, unassignable, or otherwise impractical to copy.

Comment: Maybe you should add a reference to this great answer in the github issue thread for more background on why the std.algorithm pull request is motivated?

Comment: One reflection though... - doesn't all the elements have to be of the same type in order to be `isAssignable` to each other in all directions (combinations)? I believe `!CommonType!T == void` is not a sufficient requirement for this.

Comment: You are right that the constraint is too lax, but this is because the *pointers* to each parameter need to have a common type. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Phobos has one, but you could make your own kinda like this:

```
void orderInPlace(T...)(ref T t) {
    import std.algorithm;
    T[0][T.length] buffer;
    foreach(idx, a; t)
        buffer[idx] = a;
    auto sorted = sort(buffer[]);
    foreach(idx, a; t)
        t[idx] = sorted[idx];
}
```

std.algorithm,sort needs an array, but that's easy enough - we copied the tuple into a stack array, sorted it, then copied the info back into the tuple. So maybe not perfect but it'd work. You can make it functional by just returning t instead of doing it ref.

Comment: I believe we need to define an overload (or static ifs) for each specific n if we want optimal performance, compared to reusing `qsort`. Thx anyway.

Comment: Since this is a template, each different set of arguments will result in a specialized function anyway.

Comment: Aha, so Phobos `sort` contains these specializations then. Great.

Answer (score 3):

A sorting network here is probably what would be most efficient given the low number of arguments, and the fact that their number is compile-time known (no loop conditions).

bubble sort lends itself well to being sort network'ed. I threw this together. It works and is really simple:

```
import std.stdio, std.string;

void bubbleSort(T...)(ref T values)
{
    static if (T.length > 1)
    {
        foreach(I, _; T[0 .. $ - 1])
        {
            pragma(msg, format("[%s %s]", I, I + 1));
            compareAndSwap(values[I], values[I + 1]);
        }
        bubbleSort(values[0 .. $ - 1]);
    }
}
void compareAndSwap(T)(ref T a, ref T b)
{
    import std.algorithm;
    if(a > b)
        swap(a, b);
}

void main()
{
    int a =  10;
    int b =  30;
    int c =  11;
    int d =  20;
    int e =   4;
    int f = 330;
    int g =  21;
    int h = 110;
    shellSort(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h);
    writefln("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s!", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h);
}
```

Although to be honest, if this was standard library, any sorting network of less than 10 arguments should be hand written.

EDIT: I completely changed the previous algorithm, which was actually highly ineficient. Bubble sort is not *optimal*, but it actually works OK for sorting algorithms. There's some pragmas in there to see the network that's built.

Comment: Hum... I did some checking, and this solution actually generates a really high amount of comparators. It *highly* inefficient.